# Would a 1022-keV vacuum contain real electron-positron pairs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, vacuum, cosmological-constant

The cosmological vacuum energy scale is measured to be about $10^{-3}$ eV (see [David Tong Quantum Field Theory Lectures, ch. 0, p. 5](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/one.pdf))

[image: 1]

As I understand it this implies that the vacuum contains zero-point electromagnetic modes with energies up to $10^{-3} \;\text{eV}$.

There are no excited EM states so that there are **no real** photons with energies up to $10^{-3} \;\text{eV}$.

Is this correct?

Now imagine that the vacuum energy scale is the mass of an electron-positron pair ($1022 \;\text{keV}$). Thus the vacuum energy density is such that there is the mass of an electron-positron pair within each volume that such a pair would occupy.

Would such a vacuum contain **real** electrons and positrons in equilibrium with $511 \;\text{keV}$ photons?

Comment: Minor clarification: Tong's notes say that $10^{-3}$ eV is the scale of the *cosmological constant*. Even if it does have anything to do with "zero-point modes", it's not specific to electromagnetism.

Answer (score 1):

At a *temperature* of 1 keV, the electromagnetic field (best described in that circumstance as a gas of photons) is able to approach thermal equilibrium with the electron-positron field. See [this superficially-unrelated related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/577395/44126) for a practical consequence.

In a universe where the cosmological constant were a million times larger than ours, my unsophisticated understanding is that the major difference would be catastrophic runaway inflation.