Does matter-anti-matter burning happen in stars?
I asked ChatGPT at what temperature anti-matter can spontaneously be created and I was told that a billion kelvin would be enough, which puts it into the temperatures at the cores of stars.
That seems odd, because this would allow matter-anti-matter annihilation to take place, which further adds to the energy output and is a totally different kind of "burning" in addition to the fusion.
I've never heard of this to happen so I'm skeptical. Did ChatGPT get the numbers wrong? I wouldn't know how to google the temperature for spontaneous anti-matter creation.

The usual proton-proton chain produces positrons, which annihilate with electrons. See my answer https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33277/16685

Also, In some very large stars, with very hot cores, high energy gamma rays do create electron + positron pairs, which soon annihilate, creating more gammas, but that process doesn't last for long, since such stars soon explode in a pair-instability supernova, which totally blows them apart.

More on stellar pair production: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36021/16685 & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/45526/16685 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/577395/123208

"Did ChatGPT get the numbers wrong": You're very clearly misunderstanding what ChatGPT is. It's a "plausible-sounding sentence machine". It has literally no understanding of the sentences it builds or the questions you present it with. It can't do physical reasoning. Researching physics topics on ChatGPT is like trying to learn math by trying really hard to interpret the brown writings on a monkey den's wall as math symbols, to use a rather colorful analogy.

"...this would allow matter-anti-matter annihilation to take place, which further adds to the energy output." How so? Are you supposing that the anihilation of a particle/antiparticle pair would yield more energy than it took to create the pair in the first place?

@MarcusMüller So you're saying it's just like most people all of the time and all people most of the the time? For instance, did you even realize that I did not ask ChatGPT to do physical reasoning? I just asked about temperatures for this and that, which it probably got sources for. You just read "ChatGPT", got triggered, and produced a plausible sounding sentence.

why would you ask an LLM about physics? It's totally sus. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair-instability_supernova instead.

@John no, most people that actually do science don't ask LLMs about scientific content, because they know LLMs cannot deliver reliable answers. And what you asked there was for an LLM to contextualize scientific knowledge, aka. reasoning.

@MarcusMüller No, I used it as a better google, that's it. Also, I don't do science and don't know anyone who does - that's why I asked this question here. Furthermore, observe how the actual answer to the question didn't involve reasoning.

What I'm trying to impart to you is that ChatGPT must not be used as "better google"; it's not a repository of knowledge that you can query!

@MarcusMüller It totally is. I use it all the time across many different domains, including software development, which I do for a living. ChatGPT has replaced many of the use cases I used to use Google for. You really need to experiment with it more, you have a wrong idea of its limitations.

@John uh, I'm a software developer myself, earning my money by knowing the target domain. ChatGPT code isn't worth much; sure, it'll give you the boilerplate you ask for alright, and it will cover things that 20 people have covered in their low-quality blog posts, but, um, that's not what you need a developer for – a programmer would suffice. It's really not a great comparison that you're drawing there.

@MarcusMüller Example: 1) Get options for libraries for a specific problem. 2) Filter libraries by certain criteria (tech stack, etc.) 3) Get example code snippets for the usage of those libraries. - This is totally appropriate for ChatGPT and it's using it as a better Google. I have no idea where you're coming from.

That is, well, necessary jobs you need to do for development. But I don't know about you – I'm not getting paid by the library included or the line of code committed, I get paid for the solving of the application-domain problem by means of software. If all your application-domain problems are such that an LLM can tell you how to solve them, then they are similar even in problem statement to something someone else has done before – and hence, your solution is just something that a) someone else (probably many!) could have done, and b) that isn't new as an idea. I recommend you take pride in

the parts of your work that cannot be done by a glorified autocompleter. Find the things only you (and few other people) can do as well. Because otherwise, you're a code monkey, not a developer.

@MarcusMüller Who said anything about ChatGPT replacing developers? You said it wasn't a better google. It is. You said it couldn't query knowledge. It can. Now that I refuted this you say "but it can't replace developers". Indeed it can't. It also can't make coffee. So much for things that were never said by anyone. What a stupid discussion.

@John I didn't claim it was replacing developers. You must have not closely read my comments. I specifically did say that it was not replacing developers.

@MarcusMüller Saying it doesn't replace developers is saying something about replacing developers. Why do you bring this up? What's that got to do with anything?

@John you are literally the one bringing this up. Have a nice one.

When you start using ChatGPT (or any of the IDE-based AI tools), do me a favor and remember this conversation.

The rational behind ChatGPT's answer is that if two particles collide with enough energy their kinetic energy can be converted into a particle-antiparticle pair, and this is what it calls antimatter creation.
We can estimate the temperature at which this happens by using the relationship between thermal energy and temperature:
$$ E \approx kT $$
and then setting $E$ equal to the mass energy of the particle-antiparticle pair. The mass energy of an electron is $511~\text{keV}$ so setting $kT$ equal to twice this we get:
$$ T \approx 10^{10}~\text{K} $$
So we would get copious electron-positron creation at about ten billion Kelvin. There would be some production at a billion kelvin so ChatGPT's answer  is correct though the rate of production would be rather slow at only a billion Kelvin.
But note that this always creates a particle-antiparticle pair so there is no net creation of antimatter since an equal amount of matter is always created to balance it out. This also does not provide fuel for the star since it costs energy to create the electron-positron pair then you get the same amount of energy back when they annihilate. There is no net energy gain or loss.
To capture some of the comments made to your question, note that all stars produce antimatter because they produce heat by the proton-proton chain and the first step of this converts two protons to a deuterium nucleus, a neutrino and a positron.
Lastly, though the electron-positron production in very hot stars does not change the net energy it can trigger a pair-instability supernova because  the pair production decreases the pressure inside the star and it collapses.

I consider answering to explain ChatGPT nonsense entirely inappropriate,  We shouldn't be dealing with that so-called AI at all.  My understanding is that policy was to not engage with ChatGPT generated rubbish.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine regardless of what motivated the question it is asking whether antimatter can be generated in stars and if that can affect the star. This seems to me a perfectly good physics question to which there is a clear answer.

So only matter-anti-matter pairs are created - that's the missing piece. Thanks!
